# Syntax highlight in java for android

Tags: java, android, syntax-highlighting

I want to build an notepad-style application on android that will have syntax highlighting. But when I search around the web, I find the syntax highlighting can be done only through use of an awt class. How could I syntax highlight in maybe a custom EditText or TextView view? I know that the release of a syntax highlighter is sort of anticipated, so I want to add my syntax highlighter on the market.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the `android.text` namespace. Specifically, you'll want either an `Editable` or a `Spannable` as your text format instead of strings. The `android.text.style` namespace has the various kinds of markup you can apply to spans of text.

Answer (score 1):

If someone know Russian, you can read my article about this topic [here](http://habrahabr.ru/post/204248). Anyway there picture and code snippets that can give you a direction. If you want to check out result, it can be found [here](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kidinov.awd)